# How can I start numbering my equations from 8.1?

Tags: equations, numbering

I would like to start numering my equations from 8.1.

I'm using the `equation` environment. Tried using `\setcounter`, but it starts from 8 instead of 8.1. I also don't wanna use `\tag`. How can I do this?

Comment: What does `8` and `1` represent?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, if 8 is a chapter number (for a section number, it would be the same way), you should put the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}
```

It will automatically add the current chapter number then a dot *before* the equation number. Also, the equation counter will be reset at each new chapter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you want this, but the redefinition of `\theequation` does the trick:

```
 \renewcommand{\theequation}{8.\arabic{equation}}
```